# DNN Upgrade Error - Error while Upgrading DNN 7.2 to DNN 7.4

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to upgrade my DNN version from DNN 7.2 to DNN 7.4.
But it just keep processing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Microsoft AJAX and AjaxControlToolkit DLLs in the BIN folder of your website?

If so, try removing those and see if the process will work. (you can put them back in after the upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

You may have some old install files in your /install/module folder. Before you start upgrade, remove all files from that folder except placeholder.txt.